# Неверный перевод в блоке информации о количестве одобренных и отклоненных правок

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, очередь-проверок

Сейчас [информация о количестве одобренных и отклоненных правок выдается следующим образом](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/48712696?q=%24username%24%20had):

> $username$ утвердил N и отклонил M предлагаемых правок

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очевидно, данный перевод некорректен, поскольку у редактора просто нет прав на одобрение или отклонение правок. Затрудняюсь предложить перевод, может быть нечто вроде:

> $username$ предложил N одобренных правок и M отклоненных

На SO это выглядит следующим образом:

> $username$ had N edit suggestions approved, and M edit suggestions rejected.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как верно отметил @VladD, важно, чтобы перевод для утверждающего согласовался с переводом для редактора. Сейчас перевод для утверждающего выглядит следующим образом:

Английская версия:

```
[$UserName$]($ProfileLink$) has approved $ApprovalCount$ edit suggestions and rejected $RejectionCount$ edit suggestions
```

Русская версия:

```
[$UserName$]($ProfileLink$) утвердил $ApprovalCount$ и отклонил $RejectionCount$ предлагаемых правок
```

Comment: добавил ответы для голосования

Comment: по идее, одновременно надо подправить текст для ревьюера, чтобы эти два текста друг другу соответствовали

Comment: @VladD, Да, надо, но я не отловил вчера текст для ревьювера. Сейчас найду какой-нибудь и добавлю в вопрос

Comment: @VladD, нет, не отловлю. Забыл, что прав нет. Добавите сами?

Comment: `[$UserName$]($ProfileLink$) has approved $ApprovalCount$ edit suggestions and rejected $RejectionCount$ edit suggestions` -> `[$UserName$]($ProfileLink$) утвердил $ApprovalCount$ и отклонил $RejectionCount$ предлагаемых правок`.

Comment: Добавил варианты в ответы.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо

Comment: @all: Как лучше — «одобрил» или «утвердил»?

Comment: "Утвердил" звучит сильнее, чем "одобрил". Создается ощущение, что только он наделен правом утверждать, а у нас, все-таки, коллективная правка. Я бы оставил вариант "одобрил".

Comment: Согласен, отредактировал ответы.

Comment: "важно, чтобы перевод для утверждающего согласовался с переводом для редактора." - у них там разве разные тексты?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: они находятся рядом например тут: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4kfph.png, лучше будет смотреться, если тексты будут согласованы.

Comment: @VladD а, вот о чем речь. Да, это верно.

Comment: @all: Ну что, варианты мы выкатили, ждём, как все проголосуют

Comment: @soon Мне кажется, прошло достаточно времени, чтобы принять и добавить лучший перевод на сайт!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, согласен. Поддерживаю предложение VladD.

Comment: @soon Внес изменения в перевод. Изменения будут доступны в новой сборке в ближайшее время.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ещё одна вариация на тему предложения ОП:

> «$username$ предложил N одобренных и M отклоненных правок»

Тогда вариант про ревьюера будет выглядеть так:

> «$username$ одобрил N и отклонил M предлагаемых правок»

Comment: Предлагаю использовать "про" вместо "для". А то путаница между тем "про кого как пишем" и "кто что видит".

Comment: Кстати, это лучше звучит, чем когда "правок" после первого числа.

Comment: Вариант: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566/181472

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант:

> «$username$: N одобренных правок, M отклонённых»

Вариант про ревьюера:

> «$username$: N правок одобрил, M отклонил»

Comment: Мне кажется, это один из самых лаконичных вариантов.

Comment: А вот непонятно, его это утвержденные правки или им утвержденные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Сможете придумать получше вариант для предлагаемых правок? Если да, пишите ещё один ответ.

Comment: Поменял «утвердил» на «одобрил».

Comment: @VladD ну вот придумал, посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

Совершенно верно заметили. Речь идет о предложенных данным пользователем правках, которые были одобрены либо отклонены другими участниками.

Про редактора:

> Из общего числа предложенных $username$ правок N одобрены и M отклонены.

Про ревьюера:

> Из общего числа рассмотренных правок $username$ одобрил N и отклонил M.

Comment: Я тоже думал над подобным, но не рискнул переставлять имя пользователя. Вдруг это составная строка, и пользователь обязан быть на первом месте. Я видел некоторые строки перевода, и у меня сложилось впечатление, что они очень сильно раздроблены.

Comment: @soon а, ну да. Там же имя пользователя строго первым идет. Значит ваш вариант остается.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Тогда вариант для ревьюера «Из общего числа рассмотренных $username$ правок N одобрены и M отклонены.»

Comment: @VladD да, но всё равно это многословно. И имя не первым идет.

Comment: Судя по шаблону (см. обновленный вопрос), позиция имени все-таки не играет роли. Или я не прав?

Comment: @soon под "для ревьюера" я имею в виду "про ревьюера", если что.

Comment: @soon в шаблоне можно поменять местами, да. Но когда все строки начинаются с имени, это как-то красиво выглядит, аккуратно.

Comment: Не спорю. Но если сравнивать Ваш вариант и лаконичный вариант VladD, то Ваш звучит более... человечно, что ли. Остальные уж больно официальные. Не знаю, плохо это или хорошо.

Comment: @soon что человечно - согласен )

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, так:

> «У $username$ N одобренных и M отклонённых правок»?

Тогда вариант про ревьюера будет выглядеть так:

> «$username$ одобрил N и отклонил M правок»

Comment: Поменял «утвердил» на «одобрил».

Comment: И вот тут первый вариант очень хорош.

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое исправление ответа VladD https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/565/181472

Про редактора.

> «$username$ предложил N одобренных и M отклоненных правок»

Про ревьюера. Акцент на том, что он проверяет правки, а не что кто-то предлагает.

> «$username$ одобрил N и отклонил M проверенных правок»

Comment: Ага, хороший вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант ОП:

> «$username$ предложил N одобренных правок и M отклоненных»

Тогда вариант про ревьюера будет выглядеть так:

> «$username$ одобрил N предлагаемых правок и отклонил M»