# Фраза о статистике редактора формируется без учёта пола

Tags: дефект, локализация

[Страница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/105066):

> [image: Предложил/предложила]

Зайдя в настройки своего профиля, я не нашёл, где указывается пол пользователя Stack Overflow на русском. В таком случае, полагаю, необходимо что-то вроде «предложил(а)» вместо «предложил».

---

Для справки: текущий вариант перевода был выбран здесь: [Неверный перевод в блоке информации о количестве одобренных и отклоненных правок](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/555/181472)

Comment: Можно сразу добавить варианты из http://nonbinary.org/wiki/List_of_nonbinary_identities

Comment: А Вы уверены что @ElenaSemenchenko - это девушка? Тем более имеется ввиду "Пользователь предложил".

Comment: @Other вы, конечно, можете взять лопату и откопать признаки самоидентификации в вопросах и ответах редактора, но я всё-таки убеждён, что это несущественно .-.

Comment: *я не нашёл, где указывается пол пользователя Stack Overflow на русском* - это [осознанное решение разработчиков ресурса](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265436/why-does-stack-overflow-avoid-gender-in-profiles).

Comment: @D-side, копать не нужно, все мы - пользователи, а значит мужского рода. Если идентифицировать по полу, нужно перелопатить кучу строк, вероятно, править код движка (или рендера), чтобы выдавал разные строки для разных полов -> больше лишних строк. Жуть, да и только.

Comment: @Other для вас удобно читать о себе в мужском роде, а для женщин — нет.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если расчёт идёт на удобство - надо было сразу подумать что люди бывают двух полов. А раз не сделали, значит при чтении надо иметь ввиду что говорится о абстрактном пользователе, а не конкретном, у которого может быть пол.

Comment: @Other люди бывают двух полов и чёртовой кучи гендеров. Наша задача — перевести так, чтобы звучало красиво с любым полом. Пример: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1111/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin, тогда это вопрос толерантности и прочей чуши. Приятно было перекинутся словечком!

Comment: «– Одну минутку, – вмешался я. – У Константина Константиновича девяносто четыре родителя пяти различных полов, девяносто шесть собрачников четырех различных полов, двести семь детей пяти различных полов и триста девяносто шесть соутробцев пяти различных полов. Эффект моего сообщения превзошел все ожидания.»

Comment: @VladD, чойта за... экспромт?

Comment: @Other, Стругацкие, Сказка о тройке

Comment: @Other: Соус же легко гуглится.

Comment: @VladD, я думал это Вы придумали, чего в гугле какой-то соус искать.

Comment: В русском языке есть перекос в сторону мужского рода, если точный род неизвестен. Про незнакомого человека говорят «незнакомец», а не «незнакомка» (а уточняют «или незнакомка» лишь зануды). Большинство профессий — врач, программист, столяр, почтальон и т. д. — называются в мужском роде безотносительно к полу работающего по этой профессии человека. Поэтому, да, женщинам намного привычнее читать о себе в мужском роде, чем мужчинам в женском.

Comment: @Other: Не, мой литературный талант далеко от Стругацких. (А жаль!) [Соус = source = источник.]

Comment: @VladD, их талант меня не очень уж впечатлил, даже у Мартынова лучше ИМХО.

Comment: @Other: Мартынова не читал, каюсь. (Но мы в оффтопике.)

Comment: @VladD, люблю научную фантастику с примесью коммунизма. Всё светло и тепло, все люди стремятся к благим целям, гадов и политиков давно нет, утопия под соусом героизма. Этого так не хватает в наш век :) [привык говорить "сорец", вот и не понял про соус, извините]. А книги автора гляньте, их вроде даже на немецком выпускали.

Comment: У тех же Стругацких, кстати, в "Отеле «У Погибшего Альпиниста»" был персонаж, очень умело избегавший в своей речи (и одежде) форм, позволявших идентифицировать его/её пол. Нам бы такого сюда.

Comment: от некоторых сексизмом попахивает! @Other, ElenaSemenchenko - девушка, женского рода, чтобы не сомневался!)
 
А по поводу вопроса, меня лично это не напрягает и не оскорбляет "пользователь", подразумевает и Ж и М, как по мне!

Comment: @Elena, Отлично, будем все пользователями (тут род слова, а не пол участника). Сексизм - это шуточки типа "Женщина — она всегда только женщина. Как собака — всегда ей нужен хозяин.", а ник - не самый достоверный источник знаний.

Comment: @Other, согласна, согласна)

Comment: Расширенная версия данного вопроса обсуждается здесь: [Строки в статистике проверяемой правки](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4446/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8). Отметил дубликатом, т.к. не вижу более подходящих способов.

Comment: @Elena на всякий случай уточню:  "участник" тоже не напрягает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, лично меня не напрягает!)

Comment: @Elena это хорошо ) не могли бы вы как-то обозначить эту позицию вот под этим ответом: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4451/181472?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, см. описание сообщения: «Подобный вопрос задавали ранее и на него уже получен ответ.» В данном же случае «дубликат» задан перед «подобным вопросом». Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных да, я заметил. И что? Суть-то верна. Ответ на этот вопрос находится в том вопросе.

Answer (score 8):

Предлагаю заменить на более сухое и нейтральное:

> {ИМЯ}: предложено {N} одобренных и {M} отклоненных правок

Comment: Можно добавить "было" перед "предложено". Имхо, немного увлажнит.

Comment: @alexolut makes sense. Добавьте свой вариант ответом.

Comment: Вот этот мне ещё больше нравится: [{ИМЯ} — автор {N} одобренных и {M} отклонённых правок.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3679/181472)

Answer (score 6):

Можно добавить слово «участник» явно:

> Участник [Elena Semenchenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/212421/elena-semenchenko) предложил 8 одобренных и 2 отклонённых правки.

Достоинства: всё же не так сухо, как безличное «предложено»

Недостатки: слово «*участник*» будет встречаться слишком часто.

---

Строки в [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/48712704?key=55e783241f2e337259584c1f2f733dce) обновлены с учётом данного предложения.

Comment: Участница Elena Semenchenko предложила...

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Но мы не знаем пол.

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562/181472 ?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: А там непонятно, его это утвержденные правки или им утвержденные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin слово "участник" применимо к участнику любого пола, так что идея хорошая. Но мне не нравится.

Comment: Надо не забыть правильное окончание числительных.  "2 отклоненных" на "2 отклоненные" например.

Answer (score 3):

К чёрту глаголы, попробуем существительные.

> {ИМЯ} — автор {N} одобренных и {M} отклонённых правок.

Слово *предлагаемых*, наверное, даже необязательно включать в строку, поскольку для прочих правок понятий "одобрения" и "отклонения" просто не существует.

Answer (score 2):

Радикальное предложение, требующее серьёзных изменений в движке: указать в профиле предпочитаемый грамматический род, используемый при обращении к участнику или его упоминании. При этом количество вариантов многих строк у<s>дво</s>троится, да (а кто сказал, что локализация — это просто?).

Получится:

> Elena Semenchenko предложила 8 одобренных и 2 отклонённых правки.
>   VladD предложил 1 одобренную и 800 отклонённых правок.

Достоинство: возможность более человечных обращений.

Недостатки:

- серьёзная переделка движка (которая мало что принесёт англоязычной версии, так что вряд ли будет с пониманием встречена англоязычными разработчиками)
- необходимость специальной формы для тех, кто скрывает свой пол (there are no girls on the Internet) или не определился с ним (наверное, бывают и такие).

---

Обновлено в соответствии с идеей @Nofate в комментариях.

Comment: заведомо непроходной вариант - см. ссылку в комментарии под вопросом.

Comment: @Nofate: Это (по ссылке), на мой вкус, достаточно англоцентричный постинг. На английском легко быть нейтральным: фразы наподобие «_Jane answered_» грамматически корректны. На русском же «Елена предложил» звучит отвратительно, а от безличных форм просто несёт канцеляритом. Тем более, что damage is already done: в движке есть поддержка случаев по различным числам, так что технически добавить ещё и пол не должно быть так уж сложно.

Comment: Проблема не техническая, а культурно-этическая.

Comment: @Nofate: Так и есть. Русский язык _требует_ управления, зависящего от рода, а английский (почти никогда) не требует. Поэтому на английском можно оставаться гендерно-нейтральным, не уродуя язык, а на русском — фигушки.

Comment: Да, в реалиях русского языка наиболее адекватным был бы выбор в профиле *грамматического рода*, без привязки к гендерам. Что-то вроде "В каком роде вы предпочитаете говорить о себе:  (женский | мужской | средний )"

Comment: @Nofate: По-моему, отличный компромисс.

Comment: И за плохое поведение чтобы админы переводили в средний род сроком на месяц!

Comment: Рода может и не хватить, если кто-то захочет говорить о себе во множественном числе (предложил/предложила/предложило/предложили). Итог - учетверение строк :)

Comment: @alexolut: Ну, зачем ограничиваться корректными грамматическими формами? Может тогда кто-то хочет, чтобы к нему обращались только в дательном падеже. Или придумает себе женский-род-множественное-число-не-такой-как-мужской-множественное?

Comment: @VladD мое замечание вытекает в частности из предложения добавить средний род, что само по себе уже довольно странно.

Comment: @alexolut: Не, я ж не против. Может быть, имеет смысл для особенно требовательных задать хоть все 6 падежных форм в профиле.

Comment: @VladD а еще предусмотреть варианты от участников внеземных форм жизни. Но чем больше будет вариантов (особенно абсурдных), тем идея будет дальше от реализации.

Comment: @alexolut: Если у нас на ru.SO зарегистрируются инопланетяне (Гордон Шамуэй исключается), то я согласен сам отрефакторить весь движок по такому поводу!

Comment: @VladD это уже не рефакторинг, а доработка (может даже - переработка).

Answer (score 1):

Использовать имя в именительном падеже в подобной фразе не очень просто.

Пока лучшее, что мне пришло в голову, это использовать формы глаголов в настоящем времени, которые в третьем лице для разных родов не различаются. Но поскольку речь идёт о прошедших событиях, нужны трюки. Например:

> {ИМЯ} имеет на счету {N} одобренных и {M} отклонённых правок

У этого две беды:

- *"на счету"* немного странно в этом контексте, даже несмотря на то, что под "счётом" может быть "учёт", "история"
- не акцентируется, речь ли о *вердиктах к чужим правкам*, или о *собственных правках*

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое *(еще одна вариация ответов  D-side и alexolut)*:

`{ИМЯ}:  {N} одобренных и {M} отклоненных правок`

Comment: И та же проблема, что в другом моём ответе: "не акцентируется, речь ли о вердиктах к чужим правкам, или о собственных правках".

Comment: @D-side, а из контекста не понятно о чем речь? Кстати, а какие именно поправки тут обсуждают?

Comment: Если я правильно помню место, то там рядом показывается статистика вердиктов у проверявших. Есть место для разночтений.

Comment: @D-side, если подобные обезличенные и контекстозависимые сообщения использовать повсеместно, то вскоре к ним привыкнут (а о чем конкретно речь можно прописать в справке (котрую наиболее упертые наверное читают) и смирятся. Большой плюс -- вообще минимизируется количество сообщений и притензий к локализации.

Comment: ...а вообще у меня есть идея, как сформировать различие с соседней строчкой. Надо заменить соседнюю на `{N} одобрений и {M} отклонений предлагаемых правок`.Чтобы было различие "у меня есть правки, а есть одобрения и отклонения". Вот. Хотя сейчас перечитал, и выглядит почти так же ._.

Answer (score -1):

Немного измененный вариант предложения D-side:

> {ИМЯ}: было предложено {N} одобренных и {M} отклоненных правок

Answer (score -4):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]