# Каждому участнику правок по "участнику"

Tags: обсуждение, предлагаемые-правки

На основании [ответа с максимальным кол-вом голосов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3657/176217) было добавлено слово "Участник" для редактора. [Получилось так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/132796):

> [image: правка]

Видно, что для единообразия "Участник" стоило бы добавить и в другие секции. Но тогда 7 из 10 строк будут начинаться с одинакового слова. Будет ли это нормально или через-чур?

Голосуйте за предложенные варианты или предлагайте свои.

Comment: Ещё одного варианта не хватает: оставить тут, не добавлять в другие. Добавьте пожалуйста: я не хочу добавлять, чтобы иметь возможность оставить плюс.

Comment: По правилам русского языка в списках не нужно указывать одно и то же слово, оно выносится перед списком или опускается. Поэтому из данных двух вариантов намного предпочтительнее "откатить". Но я бы дополнил вариантом "оставить как есть" и поголосовал бы между ними двумя ("оставить как есть" и "откатить")

Comment: @AK мне, то есть, голосовать уже не обязательно? :-D

Comment: Знаем мы вас: допустишь до голосования -- а вы устроите локализаторский произвол! )))

Comment: @AK для произвола голосовать не требуется вовсе! На то он и произвол.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все семь представленных строк имеют схожий синтаксис. Если менять их — то только набором. В данный момент вы поменяли одну, не подумав, что получится в результате. Поэтому тут даже голосовать не нужно: вариант следует откатить и в будущем обсуждать перевод **в контексте**.

Более-менее профессиональный переводчик никогда не переводит что-то без контекста, просто так. И нам не следует этого делать.

Comment: Вот это уже можно и плюсануть :)

Answer (score 3):

Убрать "Участник" в блоке "Статистика редактора". По сути откатить решение [вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3652/176217).

Comment: Это "решение" ничего не решало. Участник Иван, участни**ца** Мария.

Comment: @NickVolynkin "участница Мария предложил"? :) тогда единственный вариант - убирать прошедшее время, которое намекает на пол.

Comment: да, там есть неплохой вариант от D-side без прошедшего времени.

Comment: @NickVolynkin надо тот вопрос поправить или новый создать. Не очень получилось, т.к. не описан был блок в целом. Как будто проблема только для пола редактора существовала.

Comment: да, похоже что придётся создавать новый вопрос.

Comment: пойду задам сейчас.

Comment: @NickVolynkin задайте (им) как следует!

Answer (score -2):

Добавить перед каждым ником слово "Участник".

Comment: Объяснение минуса см. в комментариях к вопросу. Вкратце: в списках не принято ставить родовое понятие (так это называется по-научному) в каждый элемент.