# Строки в статистике проверяемой правки

Tags: предложение, локализация

Предыстория: в вопросе «[Фраза о статистике редактора формируется без учёта пола](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3652/181472)» автор обращает внимание на то, что строка `{участник} предложил {N} одобренных и {M} отклонённых правки.` не является гендерно-нейтральной. Т.е. с точки зрения русского языка строка корректна для участника мужского пола и некорректна для участницы женского пола.

Была выбрана новая строка, но её [пришлось откатить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4412/181472), т.к. она выбивается из общей структуры строк в статистике проверяемой правки. Очевидно, что менять синтаксическую структуру можно только во всех строках сразу.

Итого, у  нас есть три варианта:

- Оставить, как есть.
- Добиваться реализации различных строк для мужского и женского пола. На мой взгляд, это неосуществимо, т.к. у Stack Exchange [нет и никогда не будет информации о гендерной принадлежности участника](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265436/why-does-stack-overflow-avoid-gender-in-profiles).
- Пытаться придумать гендерно-нейтральные варианты для всех трёх строк (На самом деле, трёх групп строк, там есть варианты one/few/many).

Предлагаю попробовать реализовать третий вариант. Пожалуйста, предлагайте **согласованные между собой** варианты для всех строк сразу.

> [image: правка]

Comment: Лично меня как представительницу сообщества мужской род глаголов не напрягает. Могу предложить гендерно-нейтральный вариант, но для этого подскажите, как локализована строка "имя_пользователя одобрил Х, отклонил Y и улучшил Z предлагаемых правок", а конкретно - есть ли разделение слова "правок" на one/few/many.

Comment: @Mae разделение конечно есть, причём два всех возможных сочетаний (тут два или три числа в каждой строке). Строки могу вытащить из Transifex, но... может быть, вам будет интересно посмотреть, как там всё устроено? Очень рекомендую зарегистрироваться, это несложно )

Comment: https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/ Пишет, что не было активности в последние недели. Я в transifex Mae_SO.

Answer (score 4):

Не могу править ответ @VadimOvchinnikov, но суть та же:
*Кратк. - сестра тал. (с) А.П. Чехов*

**Статус правки:**

```
{ИМЯ}: Править (объект проверен {K} часов назад).
{ИМЯ}: Принять (объект проверен {K} часов назад).
```

**Статистика проверяющего:**

```
{ИМЯ}: {M} предложенных правок одобрено, {N} правок отклонено, {O} правок улучшено.
```

**Статистика редактора:**

```
{ИМЯ}: предложено {M} одобренных и {N} отклоненных правок.
```

Answer (score 2):

Существующий вариант достаточно хорош. С точки зрения грамматики русского языка для обозначения лица любого пола можно и нужно использовать мужской род.

Процитирую [одну из наших участниц](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4446/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/4448#comment15242_4451):

> Если интересно лично мое мнение, то мне все равно. Я считаю, что "участник SO" существо бесполое))) Не имеет значение какого кто рода, когда отвечаешь на вопросы или задаешь. "Участник" подразумевает и м и ж.

Предлагаю оставить как есть и использовать мужской род, потому что все остальные варианты хуже и/или неосуществимы.

- Гендерно-нейтральные строки часто выглядят и звучат очень плохо. Полностью согласен с VladD в том, что нейтральность "не ложится на правила и практику применения русского языка, и попахивает канцеляритом".
- Раздельные строки требуют указания пола в профиле участника, но [политика компании явно против этого](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265436/why-does-stack-overflow-avoid-gender-in-profiles). К тому же, гендерных идентичностей гораздо больше, чем родов в русском языке. Другими словами, это не будет реализовано.

  Я также считаю, что задавать вопрос о половой принадлежности на этом сайте некорректно. Здесь не соцсеть и не сайт знакомств. Пол не влияет на профессионализм и не должен влиять на отношение к участникам. Цитата из вышеприведённого вопроса:

  > Because some people want to hide their gender. Because some people don't have a simple answer to the question. Because some people think they know something about me after I answer that question, and they really don't.

  Можно подумать, что достаточно просто оставить настройку в дефолтном положении "М" и это решит все проблемы с анонимностью: «[Хочет девушка, чтобы её называли "пользователь", а не "пользовательница" -- пусть выберет это в комбобоксе.»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4446/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8/4448#comment15169_4451) Я с этим категорически не согласен. Посмотрите, это совершенно разные позиции:

  - Я хочу и явным образом выбираю, чтобы обо мне писали и ко мне обращались в мужском роде.
  - Я не хочу раскрывать никакую информацию о своей гендерной принадлежности.

Comment: В русском языке всё равно лишь три грамматических рода, намного меньше, чем возможных гендерных идентичностей. Поэтому мне кажется, что дать возможность участнику выбрать грамматический род (а не заявить о своей гендерной идентичности) не так уж и плохо.

Comment: @VladD, а есть языки, где больше?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я таких не знаю, но классики вот пишут: «– Одну минутку, – вмешался я. – У Константина Константиновича девяносто четыре родителя пяти различных полов, девяносто шесть собрачников четырех различных полов, двести семь детей пяти различных полов и триста девяносто шесть соутробцев пяти различных полов. // Эффект моего сообщения превзошел все ожидания.»

Answer (score 0):

Просто применить формулировки, предложенные @D-side.

- {ИМЯ}: предложено {N} одобренных и {M} отклоненных правок. [Источник](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3654/220571).
- {ИМЯ} — автор {N} одобренных и {M} отклонённых правок. [Источник](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3679/220571).

Comment: Ок, а что насчёт "проверил" и "одобрил"? У вас тут только одна строка из трёх.

Answer (score 0):

Эта проблема у нас во многих местах, не только в строках, о которых идёт речь в вопросе. Предлагаю отказаться от гендерной нейтральности, так как она не ложится на правила и практику применения русского языка, и попахивает канцеляритом. Вместо этого ввести грамматический род, приписанный каждому участнику, и обращаться к нему/упоминать его/её с учётом родовых форм.

Реализация поддержки разных родовых форм обращений и упоминаний потребует изменения движка, причём такого, чтобы не сломать гендерную нейтральность английского перевода. При этом угадать предпочтительный грамматический род из названия учётки можно будет не всегда, так что придётся дать возможность скорректировать участнику обращение к себе в разделе настроек учётки.

Comment: Угадывать род вообще невозможно. И что если участница (или участник) не хочет раскрывать свой пол/гендер, чтобы он не влиял на отношение окружающих? У нас тут не соцсеть для знакомств.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Угадывать можно по списку имён. Нет в списке = не угадали. А раскрывать пол не нужно, нужно спрашивать не пол, а предпочитаемый грамматический род. Хочет девушка, чтобы её называли "пользователь", а не "пользовательница" -- пусть выберет это в комбобоксе.

Comment: Предложение хорошее, но в существующих реалиях не осуществимое.

Comment: @alexolut предложение — отказаться от гендерной нейтральности и оставить всё как есть. Почему оно неосуществимо?

Comment: @NickVolynkin я вижу фразу "изменения движка". Это совсем не похоже на "оставить всё как есть".

Comment: @alexolut переформулировал вопрос, чтобы отделить решение от аргументов, надеюсь что так стало понятнее.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ничего не изменилось по сути от этой правки. И моё мнение в том числе.

Comment: @alexolut "отказаться от гендерной нейтральности" == "оставить всё как есть". А у вас какое мнение?

Comment: @NickVolynkin отказаться от нейтральности == добавить мужской/женский род. Нейтральность - это когда нет различий.

Comment: @VladD у нас тут спор о толковании вашего ответа. Поясните пожалуйста, что вы имели в виду?

Comment: @alexolut гендерно-нейтральные предложения это такие, в которых не упоминается пол субъекта. Они действительно попахивают канцеляритом. Как мне кажется, Влад предлагает отказаться от замены существующих строк на гендерно-нейтральные.

Comment: Я имел в виду именно добавить род, в котором обращаться к пользователю.

Comment: Это потребует добавления родов в движке, да. Но фразы, в которых старательно избегается упоминание грамматического рода, на русском выглядят очень искусственно.

Comment: @VladD ого, значит я вас неверно понял.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Уточнил ответ.

Comment: Народ, может быть вы проведете какой-нибудь опрос для прекрасного пола данного ресурса, чтобы не было лишних споров и дискуссию на эту тему?! 

Потому что вообще как-то странно получается, что нет возможности выбрать М\Ж, а соответственно (написание участник\участница ...).

Если интересно лично мое мнение, то мне все равно. Я считаю, что "участник SO" существо бесполое))) Не имеет значение какого кто рода, когда отвечаешь на вопросы или задаешь. "Участник" подразумевает и м и ж.

Comment: @Elena отсутствие явно указанного пола подразумевает использование мужского рода. И всё что сделал любой женщина на сайте будет выглядеть примерно так как то, что Вы сейчас читаете. Устроит? :)

Comment: @Elena написал ответ об этом, в том числе вас процитировал. Можете дополнить чем-нибудь? http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/4456/181472

Comment: @alexolut, устроит! Повторю еще раз, лично меня устроит! Я ищу ответы на свои вопросы! И отвечаю на вопросы по возможности, чтобы кому-нибудь помочь (в том числе и себе) и до этого даже не замечала какого-то разделения!

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нечего добавить, но все-таки "может быть вы проведете какой-нибудь опрос для прекрасного пола данного ресурса, чтобы не было лишних споров и дискуссию на эту тему?! " опрос не помешал бы! Я же не единственнАЯ на ruSO )

Comment: @Elena это отличная идея, но она осложняется тем, что мы не можем ограничить голосование по полу. Придётся явно публиковать ответы. Закину идею Николасу, обсудим как это сделать лучше и наверняка сделаем.

Comment: @Elena, да можно говорить "Участник Елена предложил", но в таком случае каждый раз перед именем надо ставить слово "участник", что не очень-то звучит, плюс, создаёт информационный шум, поэтому хочется его убрать. Но в таком случае получится "Елена предложил", что смотрится ужасно. Дело не в том, что для ответов важно, какого пола участник, а что по многим никам человек пол замечательно понимает, и, если в сообщениях используется другой, фраза воспринимается как некорректная и безграмотная.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да я не против, а только ЗА если на сайте будет нормально отображаться участник\участница, НО если это проблематично для программеров, то пусть уже будет так как есть. Я лично тут из-за вопросов\ответов (так учусь), а не для того чтобы ковыряться в работе сайта.

Comment: @Elena: Ну, проблематично для программеров — это плохая отмазка. Так можно было и локализацию не делать вовсе, это ж тоже проблематично.

Answer (score -3):

Можно заменить "участник" на "пользователь" на всём сайте. При этом оно более дословно к оригиналу (user). У этого слова нету женской формы, в отличие от "участница". Но тогда, разумеется, придётся менять во всём сайте, что довольно муторно.

Comment: На этом сайте вроде есть разница между понятиями "Участник" и "Пользователь".

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Хорошо, а кто такой "Пользователь"?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, тот, кто не участвует активно в жизни сайта.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Если человек зарегистрирован он User в оригинале. На данный момент он "Участник". И его активность не имеет роли.

Comment: Это в английской версии так. У нас была идея о том, что называть программиста пользователем немного пренебрежительно что ли.

Comment: @VladD Зато решит гендерную пробему. В целом, я искренне удивлюсь если этот вариант примут.:-)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Гендерная проблема, боюсь, сложнее. Пример: «Пользователь Маша задал вопрос» — звучит ужасно. Гендерная проблема решается только указанием предпочтительного рода в настройках профиля.

Comment: @VladD Верю, но указывать пол для участников тоже не ахти, как мне кажется, так как это лишнее действие. Как вариант, конечно, но я не уверен в юзабилити этого. При этом, возможно, англоязычные не поймут для чего им это. Искренне сомневаюсь в успешности этого запроса. Хотя и не возражаю. Род-то по умолчанию будет мужской.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Ну англоязычные не поймут, у них в языке нету родов. Зато для немецкой версии сайта пригодится. Значит, нужно разный движок для языков с родами и без. Или опция в движке. Лишнее действие -- да, но можно сделать умную догадку: Маша -- девочка, а Петя -- мальчик, если не указано другое. Мы же программисты как бы, да?

Comment: @VladD Да без проблем. Я не возражаю, если оно будет работать без ошибок определения пола по имени. Только это всё равно вопрос для главной меты. Вы бы тогда там бы и спрашивали, а сюда ссылку дали в своём ответе. Я бы плюсик за вас поставил:-)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Этот вопрос как-то обсуждался с Николасом в чате. Но я не помню результат обсуждения, честно говоря.

Comment: Пользовательница же!

Comment: @VladD еще бы Женю и Сашу угадать правильно.

Comment: @alexolut: Да, с этим проблема. Ну так не угадаем пару раз, пусть участники донастроят в в учётке.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Как-то странно звучит, но вполне может быть. Надо бы тех, кто по русски специалист спросить допустима ли такая форма или нет.

Comment: В общем, мне кажется, что такая замена — это «из огня да в полымя». Все проблемы остаются.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Есть смысл удалить этот ответ?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov оставьте - будет эталонным заминусованным. :) На репу не влияет.