# Фраза о количестве полученных знаков учитывает только представителей мужского пола

Tags: предложение, локализация

### 1. Пример

На вкладке полученных знаков в профиле любой участницы сообщества может быть такое:

> получил знак 3 раза

---

### 2. Предложение

Использовать passive voice, например:

> Знак получен $N$ раз

---

### 3. Связанные вопросы

- [**Фраза о статистике редактора формируется без учёта пола**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3652/199934),
- [**Строки в статистике проверяемой правки**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4446/199934).

Comment: на сколько я помню у нас *участник* не зависимо от пола

Comment: Я по-прежнему считаю, что правила русского языка позволяют нам использовать мужской род для участников любого пола. А страдательный залог — это отвратительный метатстаз канцелярита. http://maximilyahov.ru/participle/ http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20160515/

Comment: @NickVolynkin♦: `считаю, что правила русского языка позволяют нам использовать мужской род для участников любого пола.` — не могли бы привести авторитетные источники на утверждение? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных не буду даже искать. Если вы считаете, что мы обязаны писать уродливым языком в угоду гендерной нейтральности — вы и доказывайте необходимость этого.

Comment: [There Are No Girls on the Internet](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/there-are-no-girls-on-the-internet)

Comment: @NickVolynkin слову *участник* можно не менять род, если очень хочется, но глагол (в данном случае «получил») склонять придется. Пример: **бариста** (ж.р., не склоняется) **сварил** (м.р., поскольку в данном случае его варил мужчина) **мне кофе**; еще пример: **товарищ** (м.р., не склоняется) **Иванова сотрудничала** (ж.р., поскольку Иванова — женщина) **с фашистами**.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Строки в статистике проверяемой правки](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4446/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: 1) Зачем дубль? 2) Причина, думаю, в особенности английского языка: там гораздо меньше маркеров пола в словах. Поэтому и несовершенный языковой движок (надо было завести свойство пользователя с полом, хранить на каждую фразу место под другой пол), пусть лучше уж все в интернете будут "пользователь", т. е. **он**.

Comment: @Other, `Зачем дубль?` — в том вопросе речь идёт об употреблении глаголов, относящихся к особям мужского пола, **в статистике проверок**. Здесь вопрос об их употреблении в другом месте. Это не дубликат. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, та же проблема, вид сбоку.

Comment: @Other ну, мы же сейчас о[б]суждаем не её действия, а дефект сайта. Я бы, наверное, был даже рад, если на моём профиле воспроизводился какой-нибудь косяк в SO :)

Comment: @D-side, этот баг (?) можно воспроизвести на любой записи, например, на авторской, `Саша Черных` - вполне себе женский аккаунт.

Comment: @D-side я бы не назвал это дефектом вовсе, т.к. речь об участнике, а "участник" - слово мужского рода. Ну и у вопроса безусловно не хватает метки [meta-tag:предложение].

Comment: Интересно, предыдущие вопросы по поводу М\Ж (участник\участница) плюсовали, а тут решили заминусовать еще и закрыть)

Comment: @Other, я уже писала, что не против "участник", но уже перегибаете "абстрактный участник женского пола" и уже обидно, даже оскорбительно!

Comment: @Elena поправил перегиб. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, не вижу

Comment: @Elena, не обижайтесь, я не со зла :) Имелось ввиду что не надо в разборках политики полов приплетать конкретных личностей.

Comment: @Other, ах в этом смысле)) Тогда целиком и полностью поддерживаю)

Comment: @Elena, а что тут поддерживать? Давно всё решено: девушки не против мужского пола (двояко как-то :)), разрабы вздохнули с облегчением - не нужно код переписывать.

Comment: @Other: `Давно всё решено:` — кем, где? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, Читаем дубль: сошлись на том, что переделывать гендеры [никто не будет](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265436/6275986), оставлять "как есть" - тоже, поэтому остаётся только находить максимально интерсексуальные синонимы. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Думаю, @Other имел в виду, что незачем указывать лично на кого-то, когда можно было бы обойтись просто изолированным примером.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, угу, это имелось ввиду тоже.

Answer (score 4):

Дальше идёт список.
А перед списком обычно бывает уточняющее слово и двоеточие.
Можно сделать так:

```
$__count$ знак|знака|знаков:
```

Например:

```
3 знака:

Присвоен 12 окт '16 в 13:07               за проверку Предлагаемые правки
Присвоен 12 окт '16 в 5:32                за проверку Сообщения низкого качества
Присвоен 7 окт '16 в 6:03                 за проверку Голоса за закрытие
```

[Бывают другие формулировки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=186999):

```
27 знаков: 

Как удалить в строке \n                   Присвоен 17 часов назад
наследование - прототипы                  Присвоен 17 часов назад
Javascript: безопасны ли висячие запятые? Присвоен 17 часов назад
...
```